# I want to toggle div by JavaScript when i click on the button open and close the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to `toggle` div by `JavaScript`  when I click on the button  open and close the div , this my code I make but when i click on the button  the div disappear I think it is from post-back .

```js
 var toggle = function () {
   var mydiv = document.getElementById('showw');
   if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '') {
     mydiv.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
     mydiv.style.display = 'block'

   }


 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="toggle(); return false;">Amenities</asp:LinkButton>                            
<div id="showw" runat="server" style="display:none;background-color:Blue; width:100px;height:100px;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblAmiinties" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("Amenities") %>'  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="lblAmiintiesTxt" runat="Server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Amenities %>"></asp:Label>
   <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not use html `a`?

Comment: `<a onClick="toggle(); return false;" />`

Comment: ok but i have hre="" what i can write on it.

Comment: remove `runat="server"` from your div.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the answers in comments.

```
<a onClick="toggle(); return false;" />
```

For, href="" you cann add # like

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggle(); return false;">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `asp:LinkButton` which causes postback. Use html `a` instead to prevent it.

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggle();">
```

And if you want to show/hide your div use jQuery toggle.

```
<a href="#">

<script>
    $("a").click(function(){
      $("#showw").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can still use a asp:LinkButton, just disable/return false in the Page_Load method

Comment: how can i disable / return false in the page load